# How to change the CSV column position

Tags: csv, importexport

Due to some reason client asked me to change the position of csv columns.

They need necessary fields at starting of csv and blank fields(mostly) at end of csv so that they can easily fill the csv for product import.

Kindly suggest any solution or any hint.

Comment: I think you can chnage the position of attributes in csv file , it wont affect import! .

Comment: You can change columns position but column title name should be appropriate.

Comment: Yes guys are right , i already tried in mornings and there was no error.   Thank you so much  for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is by changing CSV column there is no error at all as I did a few times now for my client.

The only thing we have to take care is to correctly fill the options on 2nd column of CSV against the first column.